# Question about a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: cauchy-sequences

prove that if $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, and the set {${ a_n | n\in \mathbb{N} }$} (which means the set of all values the seuqnece $a_n$ can have) is finite, then there is $N_0$ s.t for each $n>N_0$ the sequence $a_n$ is constant.

can someone give me a hint?

Comment: HINT: the finite values the sequence can take have a minimum distance between any two of them.

Comment: I still don't know how to formalize this.

Comment: Between my comment and your reply a period of 5 minutes elapsed. If you are asking for a hint (and that's what you did) and get one, I'd expect you to spent more (actually much more) time on this befor asking for the next portion of help. (Sorry, but I ould not keep this to myself).

Comment: Its just something that Hit my mind before asking the question, but didn't know how to get from there. but now im sure this is the right direction, I will think more about it. thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score -1):

Since the given sequence is a Cauchy sequence, you have that for every positive number $\epsilon$, there is a positive integer $N$ s.t. for all natural numbers $m, \, n > N$:
$$
|a_m - a_n| < \epsilon
$$

Take $\epsilon$ to be the minimum distance between two distinct points, which exists because the set of pairs of distinct points is also finite. Now, take $N$ such that when $m, \, n > N$, it is true that $|a_m - a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. But this means that $a_m = a_n$ by the way $\epsilon$ is defined.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks, I misread. I edited my answer now.

Comment: I didn't get why your last line is true.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani: $\epsilon$ is defined as the minimum distance between two distinct points, right? Well, we take that $a_m$ and $a_n$ are at distance $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (we are allowed to do this because the definition says "[...] _for every_ positive number $\epsilon$ [...]"), which is not possible, hence they can't be distinct.

Comment: But in the question I need to Prove that they are not distinct. how did u prove that in here?

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani: It follows simply from the definition of $\epsilon$. Again, $\epsilon$ is the _minimum distance between two distinct points_. We take points $a_m$ and $a_n$ to be at distance _smaller than the minimum distance between two distinct points_. This can't be true, so $a_m$ and $a_n$ can't be distinct.

Comment: sorry for prolonging this conversation more than usual. but I missing the part where all this is connected to the set being finite. can u connect the dots?

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani: The set being finite ensures the existence of $\epsilon$, a minimum distance between two distinct points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19227/discussion-between-firas-ali-abdel-ghani-and-d125q).